# Trying to get profile info using Sharepoint and Microsoft Graph api

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

When trying to GET mail url `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` I keep getting responses like `"mail:null"`.

The full response is as follows:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/",
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
  "@odata.id": "users/XXXXXXXXX",
  "businessPhones": ["XXXXXXXX"],
  "displayName": "XXXX XXXX",
  "givenName": "XXXX",
  "jobTitle": null,
  "mail": null,
  "mobilePhone": "XXXXXXXX",
  "officeLocation": null,
  "preferredLanguage": "en-US",
  "surname": "XXXXXXX",
  "userPrincipalName": "XXXXXXX@XXXXX.onmicrosoft.com",
  "id": "XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX"
}
```

Does anybody know why it won't return with the full profile info?
I am using version 1.0.

Comment: If the email is not in `mail` because is an alternative email, I would like to be able to get it as well.  I cannot find a way to make `otherMails` return because it appears in the newer API it is no longer an available field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you query the user entity (or /me), Graph returns a default set of properties (the ones you see above).  We're doing this because the user entity contains a truckload of properties, and we want to make sure we're somewhat efficient here (since there's cost to serialize and deserialize a bunch of properties over the wire).  In order to get other properties (including SharePoint profile properties) that aren't in the default set, you need to use $select=*propName1*,*propName2* in the querystring.  To see the full list go here: https://graph.microsoft.io/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user.
We're also looking at introducing $select=* to get all properties too.

As for why mail and officeLocation aren't populated.  The *mail* property is set under certain conditions (like the user is assigned a license that gives them a mailbox).  *OfficeLocation* is null unless it is set for a user.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks.  In the old graph API (graph.windows.net) we would get back `null` for field `mail` and would see their registered alternatives emails in `otherMails` which existed in the docs for the new API (BETA version), but never showed up in responses.  And in the docs you point to for properties available on the `User` object it isn't available either.

Comment: The Office365 user includes alternative email (email is hosted outside, only sharepoint is hosted) and I don't see a path in the graph API that leads to this not-hosted-in-Office365 email anymore.  It seems every other field is represented OTHER than that `otherMails`

Comment: Totally understand Gustavo.  We'll be adding **otherMails** "back" very shortly.  One of the challenges we have with Microsoft Graph is to make sure we have consistency and correct naming across the API surface.  Because we wanted consistency with contacts, we delayed bringing some properties that exist in the individual APIs. We avoided surfacing it straight away, because a rename would result in a breaking change.  I'll update this post (if I remember) when this property has been added.

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT Any update on when otherMails is coming back?

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT I am looking for the otherMails too. Any idea how I can get that?

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT Very "shortly" lol I'm sure you faced other challenges, but maybe there alternatives now, after two years?