# Unable to get user's hireDate with Microsoft Graph API v1.0 - "BadRequest Unable to resolve User Id"

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am unable to get the following user properties from the Microsoft Graph API (v1.0) for users other than the current logged in user:

```
aboutMe, hireDate, birthday, mySite, pastProjects
```

I'm using `$select=property1,property2` as described in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33901737/1367622).

This request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/?$select=givenName,aboutMe,hireDate,birthday,mySite,pastProjects
```

returns the following response:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(givenName,aboutMe,hireDate,birthday,mySite,pastProjects)/$entity",
  "givenName": "Steph",
  "aboutMe": null,
  "birthday": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "hireDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "mySite": "https://...",
  "pastProjects": []
}
```

But for anyone else, E.g:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/tenantID.onmicrosoft.com/users/someOtherUPN/?$select=givenName,hireDate
```

I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Unable to resolve User Id",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "50988441-cb57-4e32-a0fc-ca141a7afb03",
      "date": "2015-11-26T00:37:01"
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get these fields for all users, and not just the currently logged in user?

Comment: Looks like there is an issue with using the UPN for $select queries, for users that are not the logged in user. We will investigate. 
In the meantime please use the user id instead of the UPN, example: graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/cde8e228-00b5-4cb6-90c0-e6991b6f82d6?$select=aboutMe,hireDate,birthday,mySite,pastProjects.

Comment: @Yina Thanks for the quick response. Using user id instead of UPN works for now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed and you should no longer see that error message when selecting hireDate by upn.